# Trying to find the average of each date of the years using php?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table in mySQL that contains date and amount. 
date runs from 2011~2013 and what I want to do is:
Find the average of each days of June for all 31 days for all 3 years?
If that makes sense?

what I have:

```
$query="select*from apple where date like '%06%'";
$result=mysql_query($query,$connect);

$sum=0
while ($apple=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               $sum+=$apple["amount"];
     }

$result=mysql_query("select count(*) from apple where dayname(date)='%06%'");
$co=mysql_result($result,0);

 $avg=$sum/3;
 echo $avg, "<br>";

?>
```

your help is much appreciated! thank you! :)

Comment: First, you have a syntax error on the very first line. Second, you are using the deprecated mysql API when you should be using [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: June is 30 days.  Do you mean July?

Comment: @PatrickQ Preferably PDO (right?)

Comment: @Xero PDO is my personal preference, but there's nothing specifically wrong with mysqli.

Comment: What is `dayname(date) = '%06%'` supposed to do? `dayname` returns a name like `Monday`.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is happening that you don't want to happen? Do you prefer to calculate in the PHP code, rather than let the MYSQL database do the calculating?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles no, I am not getting an error, rather the result is not showing the average of each dates, it shows the average of the whole month. I prefer to calculate in the PHP code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it all in SQL:

```
SELECT DAY(date) AS day, AVG(amount) AS avg_amount
FROM apple
WHERE MONTH(date) = 6
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: AH sorryy... what do you mean do it all in SQL?

Comment: This will calculate the averages you want, PHP can just read the results.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using SQL to do the averaging instead:

```
select date, avg(amount)
from apple
where month(date) = 6
group by date;
```

Comment: You're not averaging across all the years.

Comment: You're grouping by `date`, I'm grouping by `DAY(date)`. So I'll combine 2011-06-01, 2012-06-01, and 2013-06-01 into a single average. You'll report them separately.

Comment: @Barmar, I see. If that's what benic3 wanted, then you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the sum of all June days over the three years?

```
$co=0;
$sum=0;
while ($apple=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sum+=$apple["amount"];
    $co++;
}
$avg=$sum/$co;
echo $avg . "<br>";
```

Comment: no :( it gives me syntax error "unexpected $sum(T_VARIABLE)"...:(